Identifying dead-end/cul-de-sac areas in a road network
In QGIS I can find dangles in a road network but I want a broader definiton of a cul-de-sac: An isolated area in the road network with only one access to the rest of the network.
In other words I would like to analyse the road network to find sections as marked by hand with blue on the image where only one road connects to the rest of the network. I can currently only make QGIS give me the dangles (the green dots).
The most irritating thing is that I have done this earlier, but can't recall how I did it :-(


Every dangle meets your definition

Yes but the access road to the area is not counted as a dangle. It it that road I want to find

If you have seperate layers for your core network and other roads you could follow a workflow like this:

Merge all your connected minor roads together but not as multiparts, so you have individual groupings of minor roads
Use Line Intersections to convert the intersects between the two road layers to points - this would create points only where the minor roads met the core network
Join by Location using your minor roads and intersect points
Filter your minor roads to remove any counts >1 - this should remove any through roads and leave only broader cul de sac areas

NOTE - you might have trouble with cross roads where you have cul de sac entrances opposite each other as you might end up with a point count of 2 depending on how they are snapped on to the main network.
